# How to convert XML to Xelement?

Tags: xml, sharepoint-2007, windows-phone-8, xelement, xattribute

```
string queryText = string.Format(@"<Where>
                <And>    
                <Neq><FieldRef Name='EventType' /><Value Type='recurrence'>3</Value> </Neq> 

                <And>  
                    <Eq><FieldRef Name='fRecurrence'/><Value Type='Recurrance'>True</Value></Eq>
                    <And>  
                      <Geq><FieldRef Name='EndDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'>{0}</Value></Geq>
                      <Leq><FieldRef Name='StartDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'>{0}</Value></Leq> 
                    </And>     
                </And>

            </And>
           </Where> ", new DateTime(selectedDate.Year, selectedDate.Month, selectedDate.Day).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

This is ndQuery of type XmlNode used in sharepoint to filter GetListItem in Windows. Want to do the same in WP8 but it doesnot support Xml, which use XElement so please convert this xml to XElement.
    Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, I can't help but notice you have "recurrence" for one value type and "Recurrance" for another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```cs
var element = XElement.Parse(queryText);
```

Comment: When I tried this (var element = XElement.Parse(queryText);) error occured saying "Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown."

Comment: @Lekshmi The error must be occurring on another line. There's no way `XElement.Parse` could throw a Sharepoint related exception.

Comment: @KooKiz- Actually when I give the parameter element in "var element = XElement.Parse(queryText);", the above said error occurs. If I pass null instead I'm getting all the data from sharepoint without filtering.

Answer (score 0):

My problem got solved. thanks of all valuable replies. The above error occur due to insufficient data in sharepoint.